# input signal out of range error for high resolution on linux

Tags: hardware, resolution

My computer is dual boot with a windows10 and an ubuntu. Once I undeliberately striked the case, and a noise started from it. It seemed that this noise is from cpu fan. I restarted the computer, the noise stopped. But after that every time I try to boot on a linux (even live usb) the monitor shows `input signal out of range`, unless I set `nomodeset` or boot on a basic graphic configuration.
But the strange thing is that computer can run Windows 10 with high resolution without any problem. I can't understand whether hardware or software has a problem.